# Loop through all elements of a sublist while a condition is met - While loop jumping off the iteration too soon?

Tags: python

Context: I'm trying to print elements based on if they either have an odd or even index (i for even and j for odd) and I'd like to loop through every element on each sublist. On the last sublist with 4 elements, I can only print the first 2 elements.

Also, I'm doing `len(lst_separated[populated_indices[index]])/2` because it will be printing in pairs, so the amount of iterations to go through is n.of elements (which is always an even number) divided by 2.

The problem I'm having is that on the last sublist, the while loop jumps off the iteration too soon and only goes through the first 2 elements of the sublist (when the sublist can have 4,6,8, etc elements)

I'm new to python so any help is welcome!

```
outcome = []
lst_separated = [['1605', '1607'],[],['20425', '20427','205425', '202427']]
 
populated_indices = [0,1,2]


outcome = []

for index in range(0,5):
    i = 0
    j = 1
    k = 0

    
    while k <= len(lst_separated[populated_indices[index]])/2:
        if lst_separated[populated_indices[index]] == []:
            k += 1
            continue
            
        else:
            pos1 = int(lst_separated[populated_indices[index]][i])
            pos2 = int(lst_separated[populated_indices[index]][j])
            i += 2
            j += 2
            k += 1
            print(populated_indices[index], pos1, pos2)
        break
```

The output for the 1st sublist is:
`0 '1605' '1607'`

the print output for the last sublist should be something like this:

`2 '20425' '20427'`
`2 '205425' '202427'`(basically save the `populated_indices[index]` for each pair )

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the behaviour you're expecting.  Is it just printing ever `even` element in every sublist?

Comment: @defladamouse Hello, I've added an edit with the desired output for the last sublist as an example

Comment: Whether your condition in `if` is True or not, you have a `break` at the end of the loop. Did you mean to include it only in the `else:` block? Then indent it.

Comment: Do you need the `populated_indices` list, or are you just using that to store the values for printing at the end?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille The output is the same regardless of the indentation on the `break` - I'll share this example on python tutor - shorturl.at/hvxV4

Comment: @defladamouse This is just a minimal reproducible example, the populated_indices list has different values such as [17,34,60,135...] etc which I use to access another list (the lst_separated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the while loop inside the else statement fixed it:

```
outcome = []
lst_separated = [['1605', '1607'],[],['20425', '20427','205425', '202427']]
 
populated_indices = [0,1,2]


outcome = []

for index in range(0,5):
    i = 0
    j = 1
    k = 0

    if lst_separated[populated_indices[index]] == []:
        k += 1
        continue
    else:
        while k < len(lst_separated[populated_indices[index]])/2:
            pos1 = int(lst_separated[populated_indices[index]][i])
            pos2 = int(lst_separated[populated_indices[index]][j])
            i += 2
            j += 2
            k += 1
            print(populated_indices[index], pos1, pos2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the objective, but this produces the outcome requested:

```py
lst_separated = [['1605', '1607'],[],['20425', '20427','205425', '202427']]

populated_indices = [0, 1, 2]

for p in populated_indices:
    for i in range(len(lst_separated[p])//2):
        valuePair = (lst_separated[p][2*i:2*i+2])
        print(f"{p} '{valuePair[0]}' '{valuePair[1]}'")
```

Printed output:

```
0 '1605' '1607'
2 '20425' '20427'
2 '205425' '202427'
```